# Can't able to send SMS in Twilio

Tags: java, twilio, twilio-api

Trying to send SMS using Twilio in Java. 
Using `com.twilio.sdk:twilio:7.+` version.

Message body :

```
You have a new lead - Move 100088
Name: Amruth
Phone number: 07712345678
Move type: OFFICE
Move date: 24 October 2017, 06:33 PM
Moving from: BA1 3AW
Moving to: Bristol Street, Costa Mesa, CA, United States
Please login to your buzzmovePRO account to see details of this lead.
```

Here is my code:

```
Twilio.init(ProjectConfig.TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID, ProjectConfig.TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN);
            Message message = Message.creator(
                    new PhoneNumber("+447....988"),//Valid UK NO
                    new PhoneNumber("+441....57502"), //Valid UK NO
                    twilioMessage   //Body is equal to above text
            ).create();
```

But getting below error, but am using valid `ACCOUNT SID` and `AUTH TOKEN`

```
Instantiation of [simple type, class com.twilio.rest.api.v2010.account.Message] value failed: org.joda.time.DateTime.parse(Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormatter;)Lorg/joda/time/DateTime;
```

Your help will be more appreciated.

Comment: How are you assigning the message body? Are you parsing the date somehow as that appears to be what the error is pointing at.

Comment: thanks for your comment @Andy, issue is resolved by adding dependency in gradle file `compile group: 'joda-time', name: 'joda-time', version: '2.3'` which is not mentioned in Twilio document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue has been resolved by adding `joda-time` dependency in Gradle file.
Which is not mentioned in [Twilio](https://www.twilio.com/) document.

Here adding dependency : 

`compile group: 'joda-time', name: 'joda-time', version: '2.3'`